# How in Pine Script can I limit the max number of long and short entry per session?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to limit the max number of long and short entries to 1 per day, max 1 entry in long and max 1 entry in short.

The built in function: `function strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders(count = 2)`
allows me to limit the max number of operations but it doesn't help to achieve my goal, because it limit the entries regardeles if are long or short.
I would like to tell the script to limit to max. 1 entry in Long, and max. 1 entry in short per day.

```
//Enties per Day Limit

function strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders(count = 2)

// Take Profit & Stop Loss
stopPercent  = input.float(defval = 1.0, title = "Stop Loss %", step = 0.1) / 100
takePercent =  input.float(defval = 2.0, title = "Take Profit %", step = 0.1) / 100

LongStopPercent = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopPercent )
LongTakeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takePercent)

ShortStopPercent = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopPercent )
ShortTakeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takePercent)

// Start Entries //

// Long
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit(id = "Exit", stop = LongStopPercent, limit = LongTakeProfit)

if LongEntry
    strategy.entry(id = "Long", direction = strategy.long)


// Short
if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit(id = "Exit", stop = LongStopPercent, limit = LongTakeProfit)
 

if ShortEntry
    strategy.entry(id = "Short", direction = strategy.short)
```

I'm looking into the pine script v5 documentation but I can't find anything useful.

Does anybody have an idea of how can to solve it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do it:

```
var int longStarted = 0
if longEntry and longStarted != dayofmonth
    strategy.entry(id = "Long", direction = strategy.long)
    longStarted := dayofmonth

var int shortStarted = 0
if shortEntry and shortStarted != dayofmonth
    strategy.entry(id = "Short", direction = strategy.short)
    longStarted := dayofmonth
```

It may be the simplest solution for the basic idea.
Though bare in mind that if your long/short conditions don't fulfill often enough, you should reset your "longStarted" and "shortStarted" variables in every new month to avoid false rejections. Furthermore `dayofmonth` can return you a different result than expected if you're on a different timezone than the exchange itself.

Comment: Tested on several script, and it works amazing. Thank you